# TYPO3 for each not works

Tags: typo3

```
    <f:for each="{statuses.0.comments}" as="comment"> 
         8888
        <f:debug>{statuses.0.comments}</f:debug>

    </f:for>
```

I am sure {statuses.0.comments} it is not empty array, but it show nothing, foreach does't works, help me please, where is a problem ?

this loop are in another foreach loop, and parent loop wirks good, but this child not

Answer (score 0):

I just used variable "comment", and this var already used in my template )) This was a problem